# how to add a word at the end of a line with ^ without a line break?

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I would like to add a string (example: "1565555555") at the end of a particular line in my file.

My file .txt before :

```
mystrinsdsfssffdfdg
mystrdsfdsfdfffding
mystrsfdsdfsffdfing
mystrdsfdfsdfsffing
```

Here is my script:

```sh
for file in mydirectory/*txt; do
  filename=`basename "$file"`
  # read each line
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
     old="$IFS"
     IFS="^"
     set $line

     IFS="$old"
     count=1
     id="2656556655"

     sed "s/$line/&^$id/" -i $file #my problem
  ((count++))
  done < "$file"
done
```

Today, my result :

```
mystrinsdsfssffdfdg
^2656556655
mystrdsfdsfdfffding
^2656556655
mystrsfdsdfsffdfing
^2656556655
mystrdsfdfsdfsffing
^2656556655
```

Expected result :

```
mystrinsdsfssffdfdg^2656556655
mystrdsfdsfdfffding^2656556655
mystrsfdsdfsffdfing^2656556655
mystrdsfdfsdfsffing^2656556655
```

Comment: This code makes no sense based on your written description. This will do what you say you want in "Expected result:": `sed -i 's/$/^2656556655/' myfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the objective is to append a string (^2656556655) on the end of every line in a given file ...

One sample file:

```
$ cat mystring.txt
mystrinsdsfssffdfdg
mystrdsfdsfdfffding
mystrsfdsdfsffdfing
mystrdsfdfsdfsffing
```

One `sed` solution that appends to the end of every line in the file:

```
$ sed 's/$/^2656556655/g' mystring.txt
mystrinsdsfssffdfdg^2656556655
mystrdsfdsfdfffding^2656556655
mystrsfdsdfsffdfing^2656556655
mystrdsfdfsdfsffing^2656556655
```

One benefit to this method is that you replace a) the inner looping construct and the repeated `sed` calls for each line in the file with b) a single `sed` call and a single pass through the input file. Net result is that you should see a noticeable speed up in the time it takes to process a given file.